# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ android retrofit gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am developing with retrofit, but I have a problem. I want to get the results from my server.

This is my result json from my script php:

```
[{"rubrique_id":"1","rubrique_lib":"syst\u00e8me "},
 {"rubrique_id":"2","rubrique_lib":"s\u00e9curit\u00e9"},
 {"rubrique_id":"3","rubrique_lib":"information"}]
```

This is my model class in java:

```
public class Bureau {

    @SerializedName("rubrique_id")
    private String rubrique_id;

    @SerializedName("rubrique_lib")
    private String rubrique_lib;

    public String getRubrique_id() {
        return rubrique_id;
    }

    public void setRubrique_id(String rubrique_id) {
        this.rubrique_id = rubrique_id;
    }

    public String getRubrique_lib() {
        return rubrique_lib;
    }

    public void setRubrique_lib(String rubrique_lib) {
        this.rubrique_lib = rubrique_lib;
    }


}
```

This is my API class:

```
public interface BureauApi {

    @GET("/")
    Call<List<Bureau>> getBureau();
}
```

This is main class where I implemented the retrofit library:

```
public class ParametreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner spinner = null;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.56.1:80/posteboosterAPI/methodes.php/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parametre);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.list_bureau);
        final List<String> listBureau = new ArrayList<String>();
        listBureau.add("bureau1");
        listBureau.add("bureau2");

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                             .build();
        BureauApi  service = retrofit.create(BureauApi.class);

        Call<List<Bureau>> call = service.getBureau();
         call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Bureau>>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call<List<Bureau>> call, Response<List<Bureau>> response) {

                 if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                     for (Bureau bureaus :response.body()
                             ) {
                         Log.i("log", bureaus.getRubrique_lib());
                     }
                 }else {

                     Log.i("log", "l'objet est vide "+response.message());
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(Call<List<Bureau>> call, Throwable t) {
                 Log.i("log","erreur survenu dans la requete "+ t.getMessage());

             }
         });
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listBureau);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And the console is giving me the following error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class BureauCollection
{
   List<Bureau> bureauList;
}
```

and

```
Call<BureauCollection> getBureau();
```

Change BASE URL: "http://192.168.56.1:80/"
and in API: @GET("/posteboosterAPI/methodes.php")

Comment: I have tried this but i had " EXPECTED BEGIN OBJECT BUT WAS STRING " as error.thank yu

Comment: @Rushi M Thakker when i apply your example , l have this error :

Comment: Java.lang.illegalstateexception: Expected begin_object but was begin_array

Comment: ok. so what exactly u did? could you please post an update to your code or answer your own question? @JoelAkoupo